# Download error - 228 in Mozilla Firefox 3.6.12 for ubuntu

Tags: proxy, firefox

Firefox could not install the file at

https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/downloads/latest/60/addon-60-latest.xpi?src=addondetail

because: Download error
-228

What does it mean? Its running behind a proxy server.

Comment: Should be moved to SuperUser

Answer (score 0):

http://kb.mozillazine.org/Unable_to_install_themes_or_extensions_-_Firefox#Download_Error_-228